# Pasar y recibir valores de variable en PHP en Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Cordial saludo. Soy nuevo en esto de programación y estoy haciendo una página en wordpress que realiza una consulta en SQL Server y envía los datos a una tabla.

Al hacer clic en el botón de "Consultar", la página se redirecciona a un 404 porque no procesa ni envía el valor de variable. Igualmente en la consulta SQL devuelve un Warning porque le es desconocido el valor de la variable name

Este es el código que estoy utilizando.

accept

Hola y gracias por las respuestas.

Supongo que debo validar primero para que la primera vez que cargue la página haga la consulta, pero aunque coloque la validación al principio, me genera un warning:

Warning: mssql_query(): message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword ‘order’. (severity 15) in /var/www/html/intraser/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/runtime.php(42) : eval()’d code on line 89

Y al hacer clic en consultar sigue redireccionando a un 404. Efectivamente necesito que el resultado de la consulta la cargue en la misma página en una tabla HTML para poder exportar a un XLS luego.

Envío nuevamente el código en espera de alguna otra idea sobre qué es lo que pasa. Gracias nuevamente por colaborar.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; } ?>
<div>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>">
       <div>
            Seleccione periodo: 
            <select name="name">
                <option value="0" selected>Haga clic aquí</option>
                <option value="1" <?php if($_POST['name']=='1') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>> ENERO</option>
                <option value="2"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='2') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>FEBRERO</option>
                <option value="3"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='3') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>MARZO</option>
                <option value="4"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='4') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>ABRIL</option>
                <option value="5"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='5') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>MAYO</option>
                <option value="6"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='6') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>JUNIO</option>
                <option value="7"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='7') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>JULIO</option>
                <option value="8"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='8') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>AGOSTO</option>
                <option value="9"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='9') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>SEPTIEMBRE</option>
                <option value="10"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='10') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>OCTUBRE</option>
                <option value="11"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='11') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>NOVIEMBRE</option>
                <option value="12"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='12') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>DICIEMBRE</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Consultar">
            <input type="button" onclick=" generateexcel('testTable') " value="Exportar a Excel">
        </div>
     </form>
</div>



<?php



echo "<table class='peq' id='testTable'>";

echo "<tr>";

 echo "<th class='peq'>Codigo</th>";

echo "<th class='peq'>Apellidos</th>";

echo "<th class='peq'>Nombres</th>";

echo "<th class='peq'>Fecha_nacimiento</th>";

echo "<th class='peq'>Direccion_domicilio</th>";

echo "<th class='peq'>Ciudad</th>";

echo "</tr>";

$name = $_POST['name'];


ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');



$msconnect=mssql_connect("ECOSOL","logfuncionario","F3s3r2017_");

$msdb=mssql_select_db("solido",$msconnect);

$msquery = "Select 
    asociados.codigo, 
    asociados.nombre, 
    asociados.apellido, 
    (CONVERT (char(10),asociados.fecha_nacimiento, 103)) as fecha_nacimiento, 
    asociados.direccion, 
    asociados.ciudad
    from (
            SELECT 
              CAST(CAST(sys_maenit.CODIGOTER AS float(53)) AS decimal(10, 0))as codigo,
              sys_maenit.APELLIDO AS apellido, 
              sys_maenit.NOMBRE AS nombre, 
              sys_maenit.DIRECCION AS direccion, 
              sys_ciudad57.NOMBRE_CIUDAD AS ciudad, 
              sys_maenit.FECNACEM as fecha_nacimiento,
              sys_maenit.empresa as empresa
           FROM (solido.dbo.sys_maenit 
              CROSS JOIN solido.dbo.sys_ciudad57)
           WHERE (
              (sys_maenit.ESTADO = 'A') AND 
              (sys_maenit.CLASE = '5') AND 
              (sys_maenit.DPTO_CIUDAD = sys_ciudad57.CIUDAD))
            ) as asociados
    where asociados.empresa != '0099'
    and month(asociados.fecha_nacimiento)=".$name." order by day(asociados.fecha_nacimiento);";

$msresults= mssql_query($msquery);
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($msresults)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='peq'>$row[0]</td>";
echo "<td class='peq'>$row[1]</td>";
echo "<td class='peq'>$row[2]</td>";
echo "<td class='peq'>$row[3]</td>";
echo "<td class='peq'>$row[4]</td>";
echo "<td class='peq'>$row[5]</td>";



echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Gracias por su amable colaboración

Answer (score 1):

Si al enviar el formulario recibes un error 404, pagina no encontrada, entiendo que algo en tu servidor impide que la llamada llegue de nuevo al script, puede ser alguna redirección o alguna característica de tu configuración que hace que el valor de $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] no se corresponda con la URI.

De cualquier modo, usar `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` no es recomendable porque está abierto a ataques xss. Puedes dejar el valor  de 'action' en blanco `action=''` *(recomendable en este caso)* o usar `echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` .

Dado que al enviar el formulario no llegas de nuevo a la página, entiendo que el error de SQL lo recibes al abrir la pagina por primera vez, cuando aún no has pasado ningún valor a `$name`.

Deberías enmarcar la consulta en un `if` que compruebe que se ha recibido algún valor en `$_POST` y compruebe que la variable `$name` tiene un valor aceptable. 
En vista de que no usas enteros como '1,2' sino '01,02',puedes usar una expresión regular `^\d{numero minimo,numero máximo}$` algo así para 00 hasta 999 `\d{2,3}`. Así sabrás si la consulta falla o no cuando le estás pasando un valor aceptable.

Y recuerda validar y filtrar lo que recibas en la variable $_POST por seguridad, usa algo como http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php

*Nota: Los datos de conexión a la base de datos, usuario y contraseña al menos, parecen reales. Sería mejor que los cambiaras por algo genérico tipo 'usuario', 'contraseña' antes de publicarlos aquí*

Comment: Hola Jok y gracias por la ayuda. Tienes razón en eso de usar echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; según he visto en otras páginas aunque por ahora me serviría que primero funcionara :)... aunque ya lo cambié. Por otro lado, pues también añadí una validación al principio de la página: <?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; } ?> pero persiste el warning al cargar la página la primera vez y el error 404 al consultar luego.

Comment: @reymagnus
prueba a hacer lo siguiente: **1 deja el action en la etiqueta form vacio**: `<form method="post" action="">`. 
**2 el if debes de ponerlo despues del formulario:**
`<?php 
if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name=$_POST['name']; //deberias validarlo`
luego todo el código que usas para mostrar datos y consultar la base de datos **y justo antes de cerrar con  ?> pones el cierre del if  `}`**
de manera que si no se ha enviado el formulario no se muestren resultados y no se haga ninguna consulta.

Answer (score 0):

> Para completar la respuesta de Jok Montoya con una breve explicación de lo que hace PHP_SELF.

Te da error 404 por esta instrucción:

> $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

**¿Qué hace $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?**

Lo que hace la variable super global con la instrucción PHP_SELF es recargar de nuevo la página, en este caso lo tienes en el form.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

En muchas ocasiones al form se le dice que los datos los envíe a otra página, como en este ejemplo:

```
<form method="post" action="visualizardatos.php">
```

Donde le estás diciendo que los datos los envíe a visualizardatos.php. Pero en tu código estás diciendo que los datos los envíe de nuevo a la misma página recargándola.

Lo primero que lee el servidor es que recargue la página estando el valor de "name" vacío, lo que origina el error de página no encontrada.

Al principio tendrías que evaluar que "name" contiene algo. Lo puedes hacer con la instrucción `isset`, por ejemplo `if(isset($_POST["name"]){...}` y a partir de ahí incluir las sentencias a tus consultas y el resto del código.

Comment: Hola David y gracias. Sí, efectivamente podría ser eso pero por ejemplo le agrego la siguiente línea: <?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; } ?>  persiste el error 404, incluso con <?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; $name='0';} ?>